# Chrome page crash - reload page automatically

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I'm running an Ajax based single web page application which runs in every 1 second interval to update a DIV contents. after running 4-5 hours, Google chrome page crash message appears with the reload button.

Is there anyway to capture this event and to reload the page again automatically?
URL is always the same. please help !

Comment: [onerror](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onerror) might help? I'd fix the reason of the error, not damages it causes though.

Comment: An extension like https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/refresh-on-crash/nlblgnoblolmpkoniclhpnfkdmhkljef?hl=en might help if you're only running this page locally, but I suspect you're not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This Error happens because Ajax has some kind of limit on requests you can make without a reload.

If you want this to work fluently, use an iframe in the following way.

**index.htm**

```
<iframe src="inframe.htm"></iframe>
<script>
// ..
</script>
```

**inframe.htm**

```
<!-- Refresh every 3 Seconds -->
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="3">
<p>iFrame Content</p>
```

This is probably not the way you want it to work, but the point is that the iframe will reload itself after 1 second.

**Pros:**

- You don't have to worry about Ajax' limit
- It doesn't need jQuery and you can still edit the request values using `iframe.src = "...";`

**Cons:**

- Some users block iframes
- The iframe is empty while it (re)loads

Comment: Thanks for the clear explanation. but I'm not using PHP here. My application uses angularJS and Java as the back end.

Comment: @NomeshDeSilva then just call another file like "myfile.html" in the iFrame. It does not depend on PHP.

Comment: Hi @timmy, could you please update your answer including that suggestion also ..?

Comment: @NomeshDeSilva fixed it a bit

Comment: @NomeshDeSilva No Problem. ^^

Comment: "Ajax has some kind of Limit that occurs after a lot of requests" -- Do you have any source to confirm this? I couldn't find any information regarding this "limit".

Comment: I do not have a source for this exact saying, but Ajax seems to be generating some sort of Request-ID and after a lot of requests it just can't get a new one anymore. I don't know if this is (still) correct, but it seems to be.

Comment: Another solution would be to use this extension https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/oh-no-you-didnt/acdablfhjbhkjbcifldncdkmlophfgda

Comment: @Jan.J but then all of your users would need to install it, so it is not a solution.

Comment: @TimSpeckhals You're right. I just have different use case, using it too run on few PCs with kiosk mode on.